# What kind of detergent should I use in cell culture laboratory for cleaning purposes?

Tags: cell-biology, lab-techniques, cell-culture, materials

I work on establish a cell culture laboratory in the company where I work. All equipment are new and I want to clean lab before I start to work with cells. Is there any special detergent for cleaning cell culture lab?

Comment: No, standard soaps used for washing lab equipment are enough. Our stuff simply goes through the dishwasher and is autoclaved afterwards.

Comment: Are you cleaning the equipment, surfaces such as benches or floors, or supplies like glassware?

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell if you're asking about glassware or work surfaces (hoods, benches etc), but...

We use regular old dawn dish soap in my lab because what's more important than the soap you use to wash you're glassware is the water you use to rinse it.  We teach our undergrads the 3-rinse-rule.  After soaping, every item gets 3 rinses with normal tapwater (or until no more suds forms- whichever comes last) followed by 3 rinses with deionized water.  We have DI water on tap which makes things easier.  I remember rinsing some glassware with acetone or other solvents in organic chem lab, but you shouldn't need to do anything like that for TC.

The same principle holds true for work surfaces.  After cleaning, decontaminate with 70% ethanol, 10% bleach, envirocide or any other BSL2 recommended cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Mike, but would like to add that if you are trying to do protein expression for purification, some detergents contain polyethylene glycol (PEG), which will readily bind to many proteins, causing shifts in protein size/weight and potentially effect activity or toxicity. In particular, I have heard that Liquinox can have PEG (depending on the batch?). To avoid this, we'd use DetoJet for low-density cultures and add tergazyme for fermentation-density cultures.

Comment: Could you add sources?